# Can't get node.js to return a valid signed PUT URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im tearing my hair out trying to get an S3 Direct Client Side PUT operation to work.

We have a version of the backend code working on Python without any issues(so we know the frontend works just fine) and we are trying to port the backend to Node.JS.

I have an endpoint setup that that returns a signed PUT URL, here is the code:

```
var objectKey = req.query.s3_object_name;
var objectType = req.query.s3_object_type;

var params = {
    Bucket: s3Bucket,
    Key: objectKey,
    // ContentType: objectType, //(I have tried with and without this)
    Expires: 60
};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, signedUrl){
    if(err){
        res.send(400);
    }else{
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            signed_request: signedUrl,
            url: "http://"+s3Bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com/"+objectKey
        }));
    }
});
```

Unfortunately Amazon always returns the following error:

**SignatureDoesNotMatch** - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Has anybody successfully got the JavaScript aws-sdk to perform this task successfully? Any pointers? I have double and triple checked my AWS Key and Secret.

Regards:

John Chipps-Harding

Comment: Do you get the error in this code or when you attempt to PUT to the signedURL generated by this code?

Comment: @TheReddest the code does not error, it does return a valid looking URL. It's just when I try to use it. P.s. We have it working on Python so we know the front-end is fine. Also... This is the guide we used to get it working in Python... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

Comment: @TheReddest Here is some more information... showing the sort of data that is being sent and received for both the policy request and amazon request... http://pastebin.com/w3Psrep0

Comment: @TheReddest After more playing around... it looks like I got it working but am not satisfied that the solution was doing it manually rather than use the build in aws-sdk functionality. My workaround can be seen here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=519010&#519010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

S3 seems to be giving you the answer in the error message, though you may not be recognizing it as such.

```
<StringToSign>PUT

image/jpeg
1390733729
x-amz-acl:public-read
/arenaupload/vV61536.jpg</StringToSign>
```

For any given request, there is only *exactly one possible* valid "string to sign," and if you don't (or the SDK doesn't) start with that string, then, of course, it won't work.

The error response from S3 isn't giving you the string you *actually tried* to sign, because it doesn't know that information.  It's giving you the canonical version of the string you *should have tried* to sign, based on the request it is rejecting.

Your workaround is working, because you've added `x-amz-acl:public-read` to the string-to-sign... but your code, in the original question, isn't specifying that information anywhere anywhere.  I don't know whether the format the JS-SDK expects is `ACL: "public-read"` or exactly what it will want to see, presumably in `params`, to make this work but it seems apparent enough that you aren't asking the SDK to sign a request that precisely matches the actual upload that you're subsequently attempting to do.

Comment: Michael... thank you so much for correctly diagnosing this issue and providing the answer. Indeed `ACL: "public-read"` did the trick!

Comment: This tip helps a lot! I was missing ACL option as I thought its not necessary, but it turns out it is, and aws.config.region as well! Thanks

Comment: I am still getting this issue, even with the ACL specified.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle customarily, [downvoting answers is typically done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) *"whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."*  This answer does not meet that criteria, and *is* the correct solution to the OP's problem, so I do not believe a downvote was called for, here.  There are, of course, many reasons for `SignatureDoesNotMatch` so you should ask a new question if you are having problems.